# Publish web project from JetBrains Rider

Tags: rider

I am giving Rider a try, and so far, quite like it.

One feature I use in Visual Studio quite often is right click on a web project and publish to our testing server.

I cannot find a similar option in Rider, so what I have done is, create a run configuration, with the following settings:

- Exe path: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/amd64/msbuild.exe
- Arguments: MySolution.sln /m /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=My-Project "/p:platform=Any CPU" /p:configuration=Release /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0 /p:Password=****
- Working Directory: C:\SolutionFolder

When I want to publish, I select it from the drop-down and click run.
This works 100%.

My question is, is this the best way to do it, sans setting up a CI pipeline? Am I missing an option or setting in the IDE?

[image: Settings]

Comment: I try your solution by got Warning: unparsed command line arguments:

Comment: Does it seem to a warning from Rider or MSBuild? I have never checked if I got any warnings, if it still works, maybe some arguments are not necessary.

Comment: I think from Rider

Comment: This is still working for me. a few things you can check.
1) check the bath of MSBuild.
2) Make sure you have a publish profile. This is an XML file under _.My Project\PublishProfiles_ (it can be created with Visual Studio)

Comment: You can also try running this from the command line, from the solution folder use `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe" Musketeer.sln /m /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=Musketeer-Web "/p:platform=Any CPU" /p:configuration=Release /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0 /p:Password=mYuBeRpAsS` just replacing SLN, publish profile, password, etc.

Comment: I have also added a screenshot as a reference to you.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had to add allowuntrusted to mine:   Your.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="Your Profile" /p:Password=PasswordInProfile /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of June 2018, [Rider doesn't have UI for publishing](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000150164--NET-Web-Application-publish-at-local-folder-path).

There is a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-2411) which you can vote for, once logged in YouTrack.

As a workaround, one can create a '.NET Executable' configuration like you did, and run it when you want to publish your project.

More detailed instructions follows:

1. Run > Edit Configuration
2. Add new configuration > .NET Executable
3. **Name** = *your project name*
4. **Exe path** = *path to your MSBuild* (for example `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe`)
5. **Program arguments** = `YourSolution.sln /t:"Your_Project" /p:PublishProfile=YourPublishProfile.pubxml /p:Configuration=Debug /p:DeployOnBuild=true /m`
6. **Working directory** = `C:/path/to/solution/dir/`

Notes:

- the project publish profile is usually located in the project folder, under `Properties/PublishProfiles`. If you don't have one you can start with the example reported below;
- you need to replace the dots (.) in the project name with underscores (_). In the example above `Your.Project` was passed as `Your_Project`;
- you can specify a different publishing directory, if not already specified in the publish profile, by adding the argument `/p:PublishDir="C:/path/to/publish/dir/"`;
- if you don't have Visual Studio installed on your machine, you can use the MSBuild bundled with the [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).

Example of publish profile:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>..\YourPublishDirectory</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>bin\*.dll.config</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I found the same approach working in Rider for Mac for publishing a WebJob project to Azure WebJob. I've used "Native Executable" instead of ".NET Executable" and the following MSBuild path: `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/msbuild`. Also, had to specify the publishing profile password using `/p:Password=$PublishingProfilePasswordHere$`

Comment: @Crulex where can I find this password if I downloaded a `*.PublishSettings` file directly fro Azure? VS never asked for a password and can deploy to the specific slot without issues.

Comment: The password should be inside the `.PublishSettings` file.

Comment: "the Publish option should be in the right-click menu of your solution in the Solution Explorer tool window" -- https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000150164/comments/360001750239

Comment: Rider DOES now have a UI for publishing (For those reading this older post).

Answer (score 3):

Latest versions of Rider support publishing via UI. If you don't have Visual Studio installed on your machine, make sure the web project has `Build.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets` nuget package installed.